# Hi i want to fit a ceiling light fitting, the wires are blue brown and earth, the wires from ceiling are black red and earth, which is the live wire

Tags: ceiling, light

Black wire and red wire plus earth coming from ceiling, Brown and blue plus earth on fitting

Comment: Your location on Earth will help.  North America uses black and red for hot/live wires.  You should have a white/grey(only colours allowed) wire for neutral.  Think brown and blue are more in Europe.  Pictures might help.

Comment: Hi sorry i live in the uk

Comment: Usually lights don't care that much, but reverse wires will put hot/live parts much closer to fingers and at 240 will hurt you very badly.  Will wait for someone with UK knowledge to help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your home has pre-1977 wiring which has different colors. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring_in_the_United_Kingdom#Wiring_colours). The red wire (live) connects to brown and black (neutral) connects to blue.

Answer (score 1):

Red *should* = brown and be live and black *should* = blue and be neutral. But be aware that a ceiling rose will often be live even when switched off at a wall switch (the switch often receives the live from the rose rather than the other way round), so make sure the lighting circuit is off at the consumer unit before opening it up.

Comment: what is a "consumer unit"; a circuit breaker? Good ole english...

Comment: @dandavis -- "consumer unit" = UK/Aus terminology for a breaker box